# How to paginate if no page token present in Youtube API search request

Tags: angularjs, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm querying videos to Youtube API with AngularJS this way:

```
$http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search', {
  params: {
    key: 'API_KEY',
    type: 'video',
    part: 'id,snippet',
    maxResults: '10',
    fields: 'items/id,items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description,items/snippet/thumbnails/default,items/snippet/channelTitle',
    q: query
  }
}
```

However, the response object is only returning a JSON response with `items` property but there's not a `nextPageToken` or `pageInfo` properties.

I need to obtain multiple results, so it's pretty important to me to be capable to paginate the search.

I already tried with out `maxResults` query param but got not results. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I was trimming the API answer to myself:

```
fields: 'items/id,items/snippet/title,items/snippet/description,items/snippet/thumbnails/default,items/snippet/channelTitle'
```

So the `fields` param is the one telling API which response properties to include.